# 'Compiling' source files consisting of headers and cpp files into one huge cpp file

Tags: c++, macros, header-files, compiler-specific

How can I get the compiler, or some other tool to spit out one huge source file with the headers included into their respective *.cpp files and then shove all those into one big *.cpp source file?

I have millions of lines of code and lots of mingled macros and protected includes and what not. To manually undertake this would take longer than translating it into machine code in my head.

P.S. The season for doing this is trivial, don't worry, I know this isn't practical at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-E` option in the gcc compiler. Read more at: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this for the vc++ compiler that coems with Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, you have /E and /P options there. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xkfswhy.aspx for /E and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx for /P

Comment: Thanks, I know this is exactly what need. But how could I compile the whole solution like this? The examples only show single files like "/P file.c" but I have a whole solution and I'm terrible at command line stuff.

Comment: You can specify multiple files in such a way: cl.exe /P file1.cpp file2.cpp file3.cpp. Unfortunately, I do not know if there's a way to do it with the Visual Studio project.